# implementing GTScrollNavigationBar in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swift2

I am trying to use [GTScrollNavigationBar](https://github.com/luugiathuy/GTScrollNavigationBar) in my swift project. I am new to swift and iOS. So i am implementing it using the demo project, which is in obj-C.
the AppDelegate of the demo project looks like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.viewController = [[DemoTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[GTScrollNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
    [self.navController setViewControllers:@[self.viewController] animated:NO];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

i have implemented it in swift, which looks like this

```
var window: UIWindow?
    var navigationController : UINavigationController?
    var viewController : UIViewController?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.viewController = TableViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        self.navigationController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: GTScrollNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
        (self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers = [viewController!]
        self.window?.rootViewController = self.navigationController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


        return true
    }
```

it shows error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at this line `(self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers = [viewController!]`
can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be translated to Swift as follows:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

self.viewController = UITableViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)

self.navigationController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: GTScrollNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [viewController!]

self.window?.rootViewController = self.navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I tested it by using a `navigationBar` other than `GTScrollNavigationBar`; It appears to be working.